# Why did the Klingon cloaking effect change from Star Trek 3 to Star Trek 4?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, the-voyage-home, cloaking, the-search-for-spock

The Klingon Bird of Prey in *Star Trek: The Search for Spock* has a shimmering effect when the cloaking device is on. The shimmering effect is so pronounced that Kirk and Sulu are able to see it visually.

But the same ship in *Star Trek: The Voyage Home* has no shimmering effect. Here is where it lands on a garbage can in Golden Gate Park. The cloaking effect is so transparent that you can see fine details in the grass under the ship's landing gear and the curves in the trashcan.

In this picture, Sulu is lowering a plexiglass panel from a helicopter into the cloaked ship. Montgomery Scott is standing halfway outside the ship. There is no shimmering effect. The ship is completely invisible.

[image]

Is there anything in Star Trek canon that describes the visuals of a cloaking device?

Is there anything specifically about these two movies that describes why the same ship has two different effects when cloaked? Or is this just an oversight by the scriptwriters?

Comment: Klingon cloaking technology is upgraded at the speed of plot.

Comment: In the first clip (ST3) they can see the slight distortion of the background stars because the cloaked ship is moving relatively quickly trying to close to weapons range to attack Kirk's ship. In The Clips from ST4 the ship is practically crawling. In the Landing its not moving more that 5-10 mph. When its hit by the harpoon it is pretty much stationary.  When they are lowering the Transparent Aluminum again the ship is stationary. To me it seems pretty consistent. The cloak is very effective when the ship is moving slowly. but not as effective when traveling under impulse power.

Comment: @NJohnny That explanation sounds plausible. If you write it up as an answer with quotes from the movie scripts, I would vote for it. Maybe even choose it.

Comment: Scotty spotted the obvious flaws in the cloaking device, and fixed them.

Comment: While Leonard Nimoy directed both films, there were major changes to the production design and visual esthetic between them.  Lots of things changed about the Bird of Prey changed between films, not just the behavior of its cloaking device; for instance, the interior was completely redesigned.

Comment: I always assumed that the viewscreen, not being an actual window out the front of the ship, enhanced what could be seen and so the distortion was made somewhat visible. Compared to how the characters see the effect with the naked eye as completely invisible.